# Automatically silence the sound volume of Android Phone programmatically?

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing an application that can turn off the sound of Android Phone automatically. How can I detect the volume of the sound and turn it off programmatically?

```
    if (hour == myTime.getHour() && minute == myTime.getMinute()) {
        if (Settings.getSetMyTime(this))
            showNotificationAlarm(R.drawable.icon,
                    "It's time to work");
                    ///so, i want to add the silet function here..help me, please?
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register for `AUDIO_SERVICE` and then use the `AudioManager` to control the volume up/down or set profiles.

Or if you want to listen for changes in the Audio focus then make your Activity `implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener`. Override unimplemented method. Create switch that will take care of types of changes.

Like:

```
@Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch(focusChange)
        {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            //do something
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            break;
        }
```

Or if you want to listen for changes on the audio output, like unplugging the headphones (switching to phone speaker) use `ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` sticky broadcast

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT

See here

**Edit**: This is the solution. There was no need to handle AudioFocus but just set different ringer profile or adjusting volume

```
if (hour == myTime.getHour() && minute == myTime.getMinute()) {
        if (Settings.getSetMyTime(this))
            showNotificationAlarm(R.drawable.icon,
                    "It's time to work");
                    AudioManager audiomanager =(AudioManager)YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); //or adjust volume here instead setting silent profile for the ringer
    }
```

Comment: hi sir, i've made the code for alarm to show notification "it's time to work", so i want to develop it again with new function that can turn off the volume automaticly..can you help me.. So, when the time show 12 o'clock..not only show notification, but also turn off the volume.

Comment: Well then use the AudiManager with method `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)` See on the link above for profile constants and description, if by turning off the volume you mean changing the ringer profile. If that is not what you mean use `adjustVolume()` method

Comment: how to use the AudioManager with my codes, sir? (please see above, sir, i've edited my question) :) thanks

Comment: thank you, sir.. but, i work on the service not an activity, sir :( Could you help me?

Comment: Then just pass the context of the service:D

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), especially the [getStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29)  and [setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) methods

**EDIT**

You can also use the method Nikola Despotoski provided with `setRingerMode`

A `Service` is a child of a `Context` so you can call directly `getSystemService`

See the updated code below (untested):

```
if (hour == myTime.getHour() && minute == myTime.getMinute()) {
        if (Settings.getSetMyTime(this))
            showNotificationAlarm(R.drawable.icon,"It's time to work");
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

}
```

Comment: is it possible to make it with the time?
So..if the time 3 o'clock, it will silent the volume...
Please, help me :)

Comment: For this you will have to create an alarm. Have a look at the AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html, especially the method setRepeating

Comment: i've made the alarm, sir, but it is only show notification on notification bar..so, i want to develop it again..with this new function.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. It seems that OP has been answered so you should do a new post and add the code you have tried to make the switch to silent with the alarm manager.

Comment: i'm sorry, sir. Please, see above, sir, i've edited my question.. Thanks, sir :)

Comment: I've tried your code, sir...
error shows : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context

Comment: You have to retrieve a valid context. If the above code is from an `Activity`. you can call directly getSystemService(), or from a `View v`, `v.getContext().getSystemService(.....)`

Comment: no, sir, it is not an activity, but extends Service. How about it?

Comment: I ve updated my preivous edit. If it doesnt work, we can move this to chat