# Android Alarm not turning off programmatically

Tags: android

I want to turn off an alarm in Android at runtime. I have used the following code but it is not working.

```
audio_manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
```

but the alarm still goes off. I want to mute the alarm.

Comment: this may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628278/automatically-silence-the-sound-volume-of-android-phone-programmatically

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i do not want it on audio focus change.

Answer (score 0):

hey this is your solution 
i have find it

```
 public class MyScheduledActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.layout_scheduledactivity);

 Button buttonDismiss = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
 Button buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);

 buttonDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   finish();
  }});

 buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
      MyScheduledReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent
     = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
       0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager
      = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MyScheduledActivity.this,
      AndroidScheduledActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }});
 }

 }
```