# Design an application that sets the device in silent mode at a specified time

Tags: android, jakarta-ee

I want to make an application to make the phone `"silent"` for one hour. User determine this hour when he open the application for the first time, then the application make phone silent everyday at the time specified by the user..

I have encountered two problems,

**First:** How to make the application knows that the time has come to make the phone silent (when the application is closed)

**Second:** How to make the application works and converts the phone to silent mode when the time comes (such as whats app running application when a message arrives, although it was closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make the application knows that the time has come to make the
>   phone silent (when the application is closed)

One word: [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> how to make the application works and converts the phone to silent
>   mode when the time comes

The `AlarmManager` mentionned above will launch your app at the set up time. To silence the phone, check the following question: [Automatically silence the sound volume of Android Phone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628278/automatically-silence-the-sound-volume-of-android-phone-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at android [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) get it to check the time periodically and make the phone silent for an hour if its the right time.